# Saving Category URL Key in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento

I recently upgraded Magento from `1.7 to 1.9`.  First I upgraded a copy of the live site and all went well.

When I did the same upgrade on the live site I cannot longer create or edit categories.  All changes get reverted.

My goal is to change a category's `URL Key` via

`Catalog->Manage Categories->My Category-> URL key`

from `very-long-category-url-key` to `short-url-key` for example.  When I press `Save Category` it appears to save but the URL key is the same as before I changed it.

I also tried to create a new category and when I press `Save Category` I get the same Create Category page with blank fields and the category is not created.

Any suggestions on what to look for?

Comment: try clear cache and reindexing as well, if that still doesn't work you gotta create new category and delete the old one.